# access to variables in one cpp file from another (arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

So... I suspect this is a result of my never having properly learned c++, but I'm trying to port an arduino project into c++ via platformio, and I'm having a bit of a head-scratch moment. Turning to the community for help =)

Say I have four files:

```cpp
// fileone.cpp

#include "utilities.h"

boolean question_is_stupid = false;

int result = answer_the_question(); // should be 0
```

```cpp
// filetwo.cpp
#include "utilities.h"

boolean question_is_stupid = true;

int result = answer_the_question(); // should be 1
```

```cpp
// utilities.h
int answer_the_question();
```

```cpp
// utilities.cpp
int answer_the_question() {
  if (question_is_stupid) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

How can I structure this so that `answer_the_question()` has access to the variable `question_is_stupid` in both of the cpp files?

Obviously in this simple example, I could just pass the variable, but I'm hoping to extrapolate the answer to a much more complex codebase. Essentially, I want to pull functions used by both `fileone.cpp` and `filetwo.cpp` into a separate `utilities` file, so that I don't have to write/edit/mess up the same function in two places. Some of my functions reference many (say, 10) global variables, so it'd be a pain (and confusing) to have to pass them all in. Is this just **not done** in cpp and I need to get over it? Or... is there a way?

Comment: Is [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) any help?

Comment: @user4581301 hmmm I had looked into extern but this seems like a much better explanation. I'll dig in. I did *try* to just add extern to all my variables and see what happened but it didn't compile, so I must not be understanding the concept. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: If you don't get something in the other question's answers, call it out here and someone will explain and show you how to adjust your code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm answering my own question, thanks to @user4581301's comment.

The trick, if this helps any other relative beginners like me, is to:

1. *declare* the `extern` variable in a header file (in my example, `utilities.h`).
2. *define* the variable in the source file(s) as needed
3. code with abandon. So my example becomes:

```cpp
// utilities.h
extern boolean question_is_stupid; // DECLARING the variable here

int answer_the_question();
```

```cpp
// utilities.cpp
int answer_the_question() {
  if (question_is_stupid) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// fileone.cpp

#include "utilities.h"

boolean question_is_stupid = false; // DEFINING the variable here

int result = answer_the_question(); // should be 0
```

```cpp
// filetwo.cpp
#include "utilities.h"

boolean question_is_stupid = true; // DEFINING the variable (again) here

int result = answer_the_question(); // should be 1
```

Comment: Don't define the variable more than once in files that will be linked together. That will break the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). If fileone and filetwo are both in the same program, the linker should catch that you have the same variable twice and and slap you down with a linker error, but if it doesn't (buried deep in a dynamically linked library for example), you could be in for some *really* interesting debugging.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, `fileone` and `filetwo` are on two different microcontrollers, but I definitely appreciate the logic of not defining variables more than once in the same program!